# cakePHP: access data in model where are hidden

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have database of library and I would like to display Book detail. Document hasMany Articles and Article hasAndBelongsToMany Authors. In ArticlesController I can see Authors of Articles, but I do not know how to access them in DocumentsController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the property $recursive to something like 2

```
$this->Document->recursive = 2;
$this->Document->find('all');
```

OR you can also use containable behavior

```
$this->Document->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->Document->find('all', array('contain' => array('Article' => 'Author')));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had it a little bit different and it finally works.

Comment: Containable is the suggested behavior. Recursive gets **all** associated data, including much garbage data you don't need.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I gave both options